# Is the operator $T : C[0, 1] → C[0, 1]$ defined by $(T f)(x) = x^2f(x)$ for x ∈ [0, 1] continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

Let the operator $T : C[0, 1] → C[0, 1]$ be defined by
$$(T f)(x) = x^2f(x)$$ for x ∈ [0, 1]. If we equip C[0, 1] with the norm
$$||f||_{L^p[0,1]} =(\int^ 1_0|f(x)|^p dx)^{1/p}$$ for $1 ≤ p < ∞$, show that $T$ is linear, bounded, and find its operator norm $||T||$.

Proof idea: Linearity follows simply from the definition of Tf. (no questions here)

Boundedness (thus continuity):

$||Tf||^p = ||x^2 f(x)||^p = \int_0^1 |x^2f(x)|^p dx =\int_0^1 |x^{2p}||f(x)|^p dx\leq  
\int_0^1 |f(x)|^p$ since $x^{2p}\in [0,1]$.

So $||Tf||^p = 1 ||f||^p_{L^p[0,1]}<\infty$ so $||Tf||$ is bounded thus continuous.

$||T||=sup\frac{||Tf||}{||f||}\leq sup\frac {||f||}{||f||}=1$.

Let $f_1=1 \in C[0,1]$ then $||f_1||=1$ and $||T||=sup\frac{||Tf||}{||f||}\geq \frac {||Tf_1||}{||f_1||}=1/1=1$. So $||T||=1$.

I am uncertain about it. Is this the norm? also is my proof of boundedness correct?
Thanks and regards,

Comment: That's not what Cauchy-Schwarz says.  Instead, just note that $|x^{2p}| \le 1$.

Comment: Also your calculation of $\|T f_1\|$ is in error.  It doesn't equal 1.  The norm of $T$ is in fact 1, but you need a different proof.

Comment: For $f_1 = 1$ the $||Tf_1||= (\int_0^1 |x^2|^p dx)^{1/p}=(\frac{1}{2p+1})^{1/p}$. Is this right? If so how can I pick a correct f?

Comment: consider the norm for the sequence of functions $x^n$ what can you say about sup over this sequence and the sup over all f

Comment: $x^2$ is near 1 when $x$ is near 1.  So if you had a function supported on a very small neighborhood of $1$, then multiplying it by $x^2$ would hardly change it at all...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof that $T$ is bounded is correct.

---

Your mistake comes when you say the following:

> Let $f_1=1 \in C[0,1]$ then $||f_1||=1$

This is not true, as $$\|f_1\|=\left(\int_{0}^1 |x^2|^p dx\right)^\frac1p =  \left(\frac{1}{2p+1}\right)^\frac1p\neq 1$$

---

You are, however, correct that the norm of $T$ is indeed $1$, but it is slightly harder to show this than you hoped.

In fact, you will not find a single non-zero continuous function for which $\|Tf\|=\|f\|$, but that doesn't mean the norm isn't $1$. In fact, you can also prove the norm is $1$ by finding a sequence of functions $f_n$ such that $\frac{\|Tf_n\|}{\|f_n\|}$ approaches $1$ as $n$ becomes large.

**Hint**:

In particular, think about what happens to $\frac{\|Tg_n\|}{\|g_n\|}$ when

$$g_n(x)=\begin{cases}0&x<1-\frac{1}{n}\\1&x\geq1-\frac1n.\end{cases}$$

*Note*: of course $g_n$ is not continuous, but thinking about what happens to the function $g_n$ may still give valuable insight. Also, even if it is not continuous, you can create a function $f_n$ that is very similar to $g_n$, but also continuous.

Comment: Considering this and the comments from Nate and Aditya, I choose a continuous function $$ with its norm (here the integral) value converging to $1$. As such, what if I choose $()=1$ for $∈[0,1−1/]$ and $()=−+$ for $∈(1−1/,1]$. The norm of $$ converges to $1$. However, the norm of $x^2 f$ is not.

Comment: If this is so wouldn't the norm converge to 0 as n goes to infinity?

Comment: @Mihai.Mehe Your function $f$ has the exact opposite property to what you need. It is $1$ on most of the interval, and $0$ at the end. You need the oposite.

Comment: @Mihai.Mehe So what if the norm converges to $0$? You are interested in $\frac{\|Tf_n\|}{\|f_n\|}$

Comment: So $f(x)=nx+1-n$ for $x\in(1-1/n,1]$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x\in [0,1-1/n]$.

Comment: Now the norm will converges to 0 as n goes to infinity.

Comment: @Mihai.Mehe Sure, but what is important is what happens to $\frac{\|Tfn\|}{\|f_n\|}$. Or, you can even define $h_n=\frac{f_n}{\|f_n\|}$, and then the norm does not converge to $0$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$.